# Do you need to join tables to have a forign key/ primary key match in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

Hi im quite new to android development.
I currently have two tables, do I need to join those table in order to have a PK/FK match?

I'm trying to follow this design: green = PK, orange = FK [image]

I currently have this code but i dont think its right.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL statement to create book table
    String CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PLAYER_INFO + "( "
            + KEY_PLAYER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_FNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_POSITION + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_HEIGHT + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_AGE + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_WEIGHT + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_TEAM + " TEXT,"
            + FORIGN_KEY + " TEXT,"
            + " FOREIGN KEY ("+FORIGN_KEY+") REFERENCES " + TABLE_TEAM_INFO + " ("+KEY_TEAM_ID+"))";

    String CREATE_TEAM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEAM_INFO + "( "
            + KEY_TEAM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_TEAMNAME + " TEXT" + ")";

    // create books table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TEAM_TABLE);
}
```

Any help would be great 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

For creating a database you don't need a JOIN. That doesn't make sense, because you cannot JOIN a table that does not yet exists. JOIN is only for data reading.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843895/relationship-tables-in-sqlite-on-android) will help you creating relations.

Comment: I know, but i want to have a fk/pk match with these tables so I can query them

Comment: thanks! but have I not done this above?

Comment: I think you need to create TEAM_TABLE first, because you are refering to its primary key.

Comment: okay, that does make sense. Although when I view the created tables the 'FORIGN_KEY' column contains no data, it should contain the data from the TEAM table

Comment: You need to delete the database first and then create it again and add items

Comment: I have tried this many times, i have verified the sql but the FK column is still not populating